# rotate image before upload using blueimp upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, orientation, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp upload widget](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload images to my file server, which works fine.

The only issue is that, I want to rotate the image correctly before I upload it to server, so when I link to it through a URL it displays in the right orientation.

Any idea on which setting to use?

Comment: You need to set Orientation of the image at server side. First you have to get the **rotation value** from the image using GDI. then you can rotate your image using **Image.RotateFlip method** to the correct rotation angle.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish with example(step by  step).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need another plugin, like https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

preview image rotate, then crop image

Answer (score 2):

This is a backend solution. We dont allow tiff image uploads, so I didnt include the image type check.

```
$uploadedFile->tempName is the file path eg: "/var/www/site/upload/images/someImage.jpg"

if(exif_imagetype($uploadedFile->tempName) == 2)//2 IMAGETYPE_JPEG
{
$exif = exif_read_data($uploadedFile->tempName);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation']))
{
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedFile->tempName);

    switch($exif['Orientation']) 
            {
    case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
        break;
    case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
        break;
    }
        imagejpeg($image, $uploadedFile->tempName);
}
}
```

Comment: I'd give you a billion upvotes if i so could. For someone working with a php-API this is so easy to implement. Thank you